# Searching in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search

I want to build an array with known coordinates from existing data, what's the way of avoiding all these loops to make it faster? Tried with np.where, got close but didn't get there.
Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[0, 1, 3, 6], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
y = np.array([[0, 2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 4]])
z = np.array([[100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 150, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100, 200]])

xx = np.arange(np.min(x), np.max(x) + 1, 1)
yy = np.arange(np.min(y), np.max(y) + 1, 1)
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

L1, C1 = x.shape
L2, C2 = grid_x.shape
v = np.zeros((L2, C2))
n = np.zeros((L2, C2))

for l2 in range(L2):
    for c2 in range(C2):
        for l1 in range(L1):
            for c1 in range(C1):
                if grid_x[l2, c2] == x[l1, c1] and grid_y[l2, c2] == y[l1, c1]:
                    v[l2, c2] = v[l2, c2] + z[l1, c1]
                    n[l2, c2] = n[l2, c2] + 1

v = v/n

plt.imshow(v)
plt.show()
```

Comment: add actual output and expected or desired output

Comment: This returns the desired output, it's just too slow to work with thousands of rows and columns.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "got close but didn't get there."

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to speed this up:

1. you can create large and ugly 4-dimnsional masks and apply them to your grids (playing with `np.newaxis` and `==` of 2 np arrays.
2. you can use Numba (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/jit.html) and you don't need to rewrite your code at all. Basically it uses jit compilation and makes your code almost as fast as numpy code. All you need is just to wrap your function with the `@jit` decoderator. Note that not all functions can be compiled this way. Probably (not sure) you'd need to move the nested loops into another function and wrap it with the `@jit`.

Answer (score 0):

Partial improvement, focusing for now on `n`, the count of matches.

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[0, 1, 3, 6], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
y = np.array([[0, 2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 4]])
z = np.array([[100, 100, 100, 100], [100, 150, 100, 100], [100, 100, 100, 200]])

xx = np.arange(np.min(x), np.max(x) + 1, 1)
yy = np.arange(np.min(y), np.max(y) + 1, 1)
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

L1, C1 = x.shape
L2, C2 = grid_x.shape
v = np.zeros((L2, C2),int)
n = np.zeros((L2, C2),int)

for l2 in range(L2):
    for c2 in range(C2):
        for l1 in range(L1):
            for c1 in range(C1):
                if grid_x[l2, c2] == x[l1, c1] and grid_y[l2, c2] == y[l1, c1]:
                    #v[l2, c2] += z[l1, c1]
                    n[l2, c2] += 1

# with broadcasting create 4d arrays, matching x and y with their grids
X = grid_x[:,:,None,None]==x[None,None,:,:]
Y = grid_y[:,:,None,None]==y[None,None,:,:]
XY = X & Y
XY = XY.sum(axis=(2,3))

#v = v/n
print(x)
print(y)
print(n)

print(XY)
```

`XY` matches `n`.

```
1032:~/mypy$ python3 stack63844601.py 
[[0 1 3 6]
 [0 1 2 4]
 [0 1 2 3]]
[[0 2 0 1]
 [1 2 1 1]
 [2 3 2 4]]
[[1 0 0 1 0 0 0]             # n
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 2 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
[[1 0 0 1 0 0 0]              # XY
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 2 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

This should be faster than the iteration, though it could run into memory problems in larger cases.

`grid_x` and `grid_y` could probably be the `sparse` versions, though that doesn't save memory in the intermediate 4d arrays.

I still haven't fully grasped what this search is supposed to do.  At the moment this is kind of a brute-force approach, using a rather superficial understanding of your 4 level nested loops.

Comment: This is a gridding problem, but without interpolation. There are 3 arrays (they could be flattened and we would only have 2 for loops) that have x, y and z. The x and y values are the exact values in the nodes of the grid, we could go easily from values to indexes. A grid is built from the max and min x and y values. Then it's a question of putting the z values in the correct place, and doing the average when there are several in the same place.